# Opening a CSV file in Sheet by automating clicking and downloading CSV file using VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, csv

*Few hours of search and after not posting a proper post here. Finally I have come to a better and a clean version of my problem.*

Problem is simple as I mentioned in the title. I am using this website [for downloading sample CSV file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SVU13_7.2.1/com.ibm.ismsaas.doc/import/r_sample_csv_files.html). To download the file I need to click on the desired file and it will be downloaded to my system with .CSV format.

I have found and used this code to automate the process and open the file in the workbook using VBA code. I have added all the references in the VBA editor but I am not able to figure out what is causing the **Error Occurred 91 object variable or with block variable not set**

I have set the visibility  of IE to True just to check if it is able to navigate to the website or not and from the website I am trying to download the file with the following name "**AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv**"

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
'add some references via Tools/References:
'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
'Microsoft XML, v6.0
'Microsoft Internet Controls
'Microsoft HTML Object Library
'Just add these and leave the defaulted ones alone

'This assumes the workbook is saved already, and that you want the file in the same folder and named "yyyymmdd hhmmss.csv"
On Error GoTo exitsub

Dim fileStream As ADODB.Stream 'the stream to download the file over
Dim xmlHTTP As MSXML2.xmlHTTP60 'out connection to the http output
Dim strURL As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim ie As InternetExplorer, ieDoc As HTMLDocument 'ie objects to get the url for the file

'first the page to navigate to. This sets up a current session ID which we can then query for the corresponding file
strURL = "https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SVU13_7.2.1/com.ibm.ismsaas.doc/import/r_sample_csv_files.html"

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate strURL

'best to wait until ie has finished getting the page
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

'get the document
Set ieDoc = ie.Document

'the download button is called "downloadData", getElementById returns the url we need.
strFile = ieDoc.getElementById("AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv")

'now get the file using ADODB
Set xmlHTTP = New MSXML2.xmlHTTP60
xmlHTTP.Open "GET", strFile
xmlHTTP.send

If xmlHTTP.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "File not found"
    GoTo exitsub
End If

'now write the responseBody to a file as a csv, using an ADODB stream
Set fileStream = New ADODB.Stream
With fileStream
    .Open
    .Type = adTypeBinary
    .Write xmlHTTP.responseBody
    .Position = 0
    .SaveToFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd hhmmss") & ".csv"
    .Close
End With

'done
exitsub: 'very cursory error trapping in this, you should probably look after that.
If Err Then
    MsgBox "Error occurred " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly
End If
'Tidy up
ie.Quit
Set ieDoc = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
Set fileStream = Nothing
Set xmlHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am not able to figure out is causing this error, I can see that all the set variables are closed properly but I do need help of the community for it to work.

Help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I am forever curious on why it doesn't seem important to disclose on what line the error is being generated on.

Comment: If you are including the *Microsoft XML, v6.0* library then use `Dim xmlHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` and `Set xmlHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` (but your Option Explicit should have caught that).

Comment: Comment out your error handler - where does it fail?

Comment: @Jeeped I got the following error "Error Occurred 91... " So I think the error occurred at the line 91 if I am correct?

Comment: @Jeeped My apologies for not doing the correction in the code, In the original code I am using  ".XMLHTTP60" and I have made the corrections here. Thanks

Comment: @Jeeped Okay so I just checked that Error occurred 91 is the error code itself. May I know that how exactly I can see that at which line this error has occurred because there is no highlight of text or anything in the VBA editor.

Comment: No. **91** is the error code, not the line it occurs on. Comment out `'On Error GoTo exitsub` then run through by repeatedly tapping F8. When you run into an error choose **Debug** and it will take you to the line containing the error.

Comment: @Jeeped Okay so I run the code line by line and debugged it as you said and I found that the error is occurring at line of code where I am declaring the strfile to get the element by ID. "strFile = ieDoc.getElementById("AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv")"

Comment: I looked at that page. There is no `id="AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv" parameter inside that anchor (i.e. `<a>`) element. You should probably try using `getelementsbyclass("xref ibm-forward-link") and loop through the results. You also need to return the `.href` from that element once found.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for helping me out but as far as I know GetElementsByClassName is not a method available in the Microsoft XML, v6.0 library.

Comment: @Jeeped "AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv" is a link on the webpage and when we click it we get the .CSV file. That is what I am trying to implement.

Comment: The link is inside a table that is inside an iFrame. You are going to have to get inside the iframe before you can access the `<a>` anchor.